# Walking a directory, looking for .xls files and glob is ignoring them (Python and glob module)

Tags: python-3.x, glob

I wrote a for loop that walks a directory tree and does successfully return all the files names.  The sub folders include .pdf files so I'm trying to extract data only from the .xls files.  Using glob('*.xls') is not working for some reason.

They are not .xlsx extensions but rather .xls so that's not the issue.  I have run print functions to test the directory walk (it works) but then I cannot seem to grab files with extension .xls.

```
import os
from glob import glob

for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('C:\\Users\\userName\\someFiles'):
    print('The current folder is ' + folderName)

    for subfolder in subfolders:
        print('SUBFOLDER OF ' + folderName + ': ' + subfolder)
    for filename in filenames:
        dataPrint = glob('*.xls')
        print('File Name is: '+filename+ ' Glob name is: '+str(dataPrint))
```

This works to this extent:

```
The current folder is C:\Users\\userName\\someFiles\subFolder
File Name is: Sample Data March 2019.pdf Glob name is: []
File Name is: File 1 March 2019.pdf Glob name is: []
File Name is: File 1 March 2019.xls Glob name is: []
```

You can see how glob comes up blank.  I can't figure it out because glob has never let me down before! Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

this might work for you

```
import os
from glob import glob
path = 'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\glob\\target'

for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path):

    for subfolder in subfolders:
        print('SUBFOLDER OF ' + folderName + ': ' + subfolder)
    for filename in filenames:
        dataPrint = glob(path+'\\*.xlsx')
        print('File Name is: '+filename+ ' Glob name is: '+str(dataPrint))
```

Comment: Still coming up blank, however, I'm not sure I understand your path variable.  Why do you have glob in it?

Comment: Hi, the path variable contained glob, because I used that in a folder name to test it. You can call it whatever you want; but it should point to the folder containing the files you want to list. The reason it might turn up blank for you is that I changed the extension to `.xlsx` in stead of `.xls`

Comment: ok, that's what I thought so I ignored it.  I also caught .xlsx.  Still coming up blank.  It's very odd.

Comment: Could it be related then to your subfolders? The *.xls will search for any filename with an XLS extension, but I don't think it'll look in subfolders of path. If you have only one level of folders below the path variable you could simply use another asterix like this: `dataPrint = glob(path+'\\*\\*.xls')`

Comment: That catches the entire path as the glob name.  This is very perplexing.

Comment: I'm not sure, but as you're using subfolders, it is always going to return some part of the full path to the file. I tested it and you can ditch the path, but the two asterixes are needed to make it work. If you have to keep using glob, you can modify the string to extract the substring after the last `\` or you can might give os.walk and endswith() a try to find all the .xls files. For my own use I tend to lean to the latter.